# actionbar not appearing with ListView

Tags: android, layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to get my action bar to show up. It does show up in the visual appearance in Android Studio, but when I run the app, it does not show up in the emulator or a device.

Here is the current xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: which api version u r running app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActionBar was introduced in `api level 11` ,so if your `android:minSdkVersion` is less than 11 the actionbar will not be shown in the devices with android version less `3.0 i.e api level 11` .